# GPU metrics in Datadog

Tags: gpu, datadog

I'm using GPU Operator and DCGM exporter for collecting GPU metrics on AWS EKS cluster.

How can I configure Datadog to scrape custom GPU metrics from DCGM exporter (`/metrics` path and port `9400`) container since this container is not too much configurable inside helm release.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/dcgm/?tab=kubernetes.